# How do I solve merge conflicts on a protected branch?

Tags: git

I have a branch that's branched of a `master` branch. It's more of a `release` branch, if you will. This `release` branch is protected.

```
master ---> release
```

and from this `release` branch, I've been branching my features off of it and merging it in:

```
master ---> release <--- features
```

now once my features are into this `release` branch, there are merge conflicts. Herein lies my problem. I know how to solve conflicts were it not a protected branch, but I'm not sure how to solve it otherwise.

What I've tried doing was something like this:

```
master ---> release ---> release-fix
```

and in `release-fix`, I would rebase from `master` and push it up, and make the base of that PR to be the `release` branch. However when I make the PR, it says it's still unable to automatically merge. Is this the right way to do something like this?

Answer (score 16):

I think there are multiple ways to do this, one being Dherik's answer. I typically do the opposite:

1. `git fetch` # get copy of latest everything
2. `git checkout -b merge-release-into-master origin/master --no-track` # create a new branch off of master
3. `git merge origin/release --no-ff` # merge in the release branch
4. Resolve all the conflicts and commit.
5. `push -u merge-release-into-master` # Push out your new **merge-release-into-master** branch and PR it into **master**. Now it should go cleanly.

As a side note, are multiple people merging into master in this way (multiple release or hotfix branches simultaneously)? If no, I'm not sure how you're getting merge conflicts in the first place from release into master.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a new branch from the `release` branch (as you did, creating the `release-fix`), merge the "conflicted" feature on this new branch, resolve the conflicts and open a new pull/merge request from the new branch to the `release` branch.

I'm not aware about the "automatically merge" that you mentioned, but I think this is the easiest way to resolve the problem that you describe when working with protected branches.